# not able to get values in entity framework sometimes(i suspect there is issue with context creation)

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am getting null in the below statement sometimes.

```
 public GlobalEnums.AuthenticationResults Authenticate(UserLoginDTO Login, bool skipPolicy = false, bool skipUpdateLastLoggedOn = false)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = new eNextDALEntities())
             {
                List<tblUser> lstUser = context.tblUsers
                                                    .Where(usr => (string.Compare(usr.UserName, Login.UserName, true) == 0))
                                                    .ToList();


                            Int32 userCnt = lstUser.Count;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

so it results in throwing error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

It rarely shows this behavior. 
I am unable to understand this strange behavior. It would be helpful if someone explains me why and how of this behavior or else point me in the right direction of how I can avoid this situation.

**I think it might be related to context creation but not sure though. Even if it is how should I solve it.**

Calling Code -

```
public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
        string userName = "";

        if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues("UserName", out headerValues))
        {
            userName = headerValues.First();
        }

        UserLoginDTO user = new UserLoginDTO();

        user.UserName = userName;

        if (userName == "")
        {
            return ControllerContext.Request
                   .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Please provide the credentials.");
        }

        GlobalEnums.AuthenticationResults _login = _repository.Authenticate(user);

        if (!_login.Equals(GlobalEnums.AuthenticationResults.Authenticated))
        {
            return ControllerContext.Request
                   .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, _login.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            return ControllerContext.Request
                       .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

Also the point that I am thinking is even if username is null or wrong and it doesnt get any data then also `context.tblUsers
                                                        .Where(usr => (string.Compare(usr.UserName, Login.UserName, true) == 0))
                                                        .ToList();`
will return empty list but it will not return null. It can return null only if there is some issue with context

**STACK TRACE:**

> Stack Trace: at LoginRepository.Authenticate(UserLoginDTO Login)
>   at Controllers.LoginController.Authenticate()
>   at lambdamethod(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>cDisplayClass10.b9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

```
                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
```

at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()

```
                       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()

                    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
```

at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d_0.MoveNext()

Comment: What about Login.UserName? Where does that get set and could it be null? Expired session, etc.

Comment: i am passing this Login object

Comment: it happens mostly first time then afterwards it works fine with same code.

Comment: I would look at how Login.UserName is set and if it can possibly be null. Otherwise show the code that calls this code (controller, filter, etc).